# How to configure log4j in WebApp?

Tags: jakarta-ee, log4j

I want to use log4j in my webapplication. Even though i have added log4j.props in src directory, log4j is not finding it and prints everything in console. But in standalone java app, it is finding in classspath. Why not in webapp.? I have to write a listener and load it manually?

Answer (score 0):

It would seem that you have not bootstrapped log4j to the web server or the app server where you are deploying your war. You will have to configure your server to use log4j. For details on how to bootstrap, you can check out the documentation presented in their respective sites.

Cheers

Comment: Please use comments rather than answers for advises.